# Scons set s directory as NoClean

Tags: c++, build, scons

I'm using scons as my build system of c++.

There's a sub directory that contains a static library.

I've tried to set:

```py
NoClean("${PATH_TO_DIR}")
```

But the files in this directory are still removed by `scons -c`.

Is there a way to prevent this command from removing all files generated in this directory?

Comment: Btw, do you build the library using SCons? If not, the file won't be deleted. SCons cleans only what it can build back. If you do build the library, why to prevent cleaning it?

Comment: @NO_NAME True. It didn't work at that time. But I forgot to update my answer. I made a shell script to delete these file manually in the end. :P

Comment: If PATH_TO_DIR is an Environment() variable, NoClean() won't have access to that.  You'd need to use `env.NoClean("${PATH_TO_DIR}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag `-c` works more or less like this:

1. List all the files that could be built by this call of `scons` if the flag was not there.
2. Add to the list relevant files marked to be cleaned with `Clean()`.
3. Delete from the list the files marked with `NoClean()` (non-recursively).
4. Remove all the files that are remaining on the list from the filesystem.

SCons is very focused on files and it doesn't work that well with directories. Usually, it just creates them automatically whenever they are needed and for the rest of the time it pretends they doesn't exist and it is all a flat file-system. It doesn't even delete automatically created directories so your `NoClean()` is double-ineffective :-) (You would need to call `Clean()` on the directory for SCons to be able to remove it during cleaning.)

I think your only option is to call `NoClean()` for every file that you create in this directory. (If you have the list/set of those files lying somewhere, you can just call `NoClean()` once, passing the list to it.)

Comment: `NoClean` to every one is an unacceptable solution for me since there are too many files.. Never mind, I've just written a .sh file that delete these *.os file to avoid using `Clean`.

Comment: @ParallelParadox Why .sh? In SCons you have full power of Python to work with. You could write a function that removes some specific files and create an `Alias()` to use it as pseudo-target. Or you could write a function that finds all the files you don't want to remove and call `NoClean()`.

Comment: _(: D > ∠)_ That's a new idea for me, let me read the official document..

Answer (score 0):

`scons -c .` will only remove the target file under the certain directory. So this is a fallback to resolve my problem.